# Running speed - treadmill vs outdoor

Tags: running, treadmill

I've found that by running comfortably on a treadmill for 30 minutes, I average 9 km/h, and I've tested this on several different treadmills.

When I go running outside, RunKeeper or some other tracking device tell me my pace is closer to 11 km/h , 12 km/h.

I'm wondering what the likely reason for this? Perceived difficulty is different between the two, device(s) are not accurate, having to propel yourself forwards means you naturally go faster??

Comment: Your most likely culprit is heat. A lot of people run slower due to heat buildup, because you don't have the breeze of running to cool you off. I don't run slower, but I find that I can't run as long on a treadmill (or on a bike trainer for that matter) for that reason.

Comment: Maybe you are not running straight? If you are zigzagging, no treadmill will notice that, but a device you are carrying might just get it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Given that outside running utilizes different terrains, some steeper than others, it's possible that your terrain slopes downhill or you usually run with the wind, thus making your speed faster. 
 
It could also be that the mechanics by which each device measures speed varies slightly *(due to the materials used)*. 
 
Lastly, given that on a treadmill, you are actually exerting more speed to counteract the backward movement of the belt *(running outdoors doesn't have that)*, it's possible that your net speed is reduced, thus the values shown on the treadmills.

Comment: No, you aren't running faster to counteract the belt. I forget where I saw it, but there were a bunch of physicists debating it and that was debunked. (If anything, the belt would make it easier, not harder).

Comment: @JohnP I haven't checked the articles on the subject; however, explain how the belt moving backwards will increase *(and not decrease)* a runner's speed. Thanks.

Comment: Because the belt theoretically "pulls" the foot back faster, which makes it easier to maintain a higher speed. All of that was basically disproven, running on a treadmill is only very marginally different than running outside.

Comment: If the belt's moving backward while your feet's moving forward, how does that enable you to maintain a higher speed? To maintain the same speed, won't you need to go at a higher speed in order to counteract the backward pull? Basic Physics *(and experience on treadmills)* supports this theory; hopefully, you have an advanced Physics theory to disprove it.

Comment: Your feet move forward in the air, not on the ground. Your feet move backward (in the same direction as the belt) to propel you forward. I don't have physics and never understood the argument, I just read it (Wish I could remember where).

Comment: I hope you've ran on the treadmill before; if that's the case, this illustration should be easier to relate with: Have you ever increased your treadmill's speed while on it? Did you initially feel a backward push by the belt before you increased your speed to match the treadmill's? If you have, then, you can understand the belt's natural inclination to push you backwards. I couldn't find any article on the matter and it seems like an interesting case. Please, post the articles if you ever found them. I'd like to learn more about it. Thanks.

Comment: Treadmill running and in-world running are no different  from each other except for wind resistance.  The reason you feel pushed back by the belt is because the ground is moving faster in relation to you, which means you must move faster.  Thought-experiment it to an extreme: if the belt is 1km square, and you start running to the end, and then the belt starts moving, are you using any more or less energy now that the belt is moving?

Comment: @jamuraa apart from wind resistance, terrain is also a difference between treadmill and outdoor running. And yes, you are correct that you must move faster if the ground is moving against you, meaning that your actual speed should be a little higher than what's registered. I can't seem to find any article explaining the phenomenon but that's just basic physics.

Answer (score 1):

Treadmill running is much easier, unless it it one of the running road, and would be the reason for the difference in pace.  The reason I say this, is because the treadmill does all of the work.  All you are doing is keeping up with it.

The other reason, is outside the gradient naturally changes even under foot.  Your body has to work more to move in a forward direction than on a treadmill.  (ouside is like working on an unstable base in the gym - its harder) you also have the weather to contend with.  Even a flat route outside would greatly use more muscles and effort.

Personally, I would only use a treadmill to warm up, or for a run when the outside option was not available.

- running road treadmills are manually propelled ie you do the work. I think this could be more closely compared to outside running

Comment: I agree with your answer, but in OP's case he ran faster outdoors, which goes against this explanation. I can only think that he might want to try a higher treadmill setting; do you have any other ideas for the reversed case?